# Crystal Reports Group Header with Formula Field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011

So I made a Crystal Report with some custom Group headers(ie. Created a formula field based off  database data then used it in a group header). The Formula specifically that seems to be giving me trouble is:

```
IF {Quote.Field1} = true THEN "Incremental Sales Assist"
ELSE IF {Quote.Field2} = "Yes" THEN "Fulfillment"
ELSE "Sales Assist"
```

When the report generates it appears to ignore the else.

[image: grouptree]

If you expand the tree where the arrow is with no text next to it, it does provide the correct data that should be grouped with "Sales Assists" I just don't understand why the text is not showing there...Has anyone else encountered anything like this? Is it a crystal bug or can I just not do this? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should definitely be able to do it, I've done it many times. It should also show last in the list since CR sorts alphabetically. Have you tried ELSE IF ({Quote.Field1 <> True AND Quote.Field2 = "No") then "Sales Assist"?

Comment: That's what I thought but Yes I tried that also. Tried it again just now to make sure...still no "Sales Assist". Something else must be going on. Ill keep trying. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried viewing it in a viewer instead of CR 2011?

Comment: I am using a viewer. Tried in CR also, "Sales Assist" showed but there was still a blank branch. I changed the field to a SQL Expression Field and it's fixed. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you were able to resolve it.

Comment: You know what, I just had a thought. In the File menu, see if under Report Options the "Convert Null Values to Default" is checked. Let me know if that does anything.

Comment: "Convert Null Values to Default" is not checked, Checking it didn't seem to change the issue either. (+1 for the continued effort)

Comment: There are two checkboxes that will convert NULL values to Default. Sometimes when you get a blank record it is because it doesn't have a value in the database. So I thought maybe that could be the reason you get a blank label but the correct data. Worth a shot and thanks for the upvote!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the above and was getting a blank value for the last output of the IF statement.

I resolved it by recreating the `Formula Field` as a `SQL Expression Field` then using that as my grouping field.